# Django elastic search populate foreign key fields

Tags: python, django, elasticsearch

I have a user model and I have extended it with a profile model:

```
class ProfileIndex(indexes.SearchIndex, indexes.Indexable):
    text = indexes.CharField(document=True, use_template=True)
    username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')
    first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='first_name')
    last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='last_name')
    user = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user')

    def get_model(self):
        return Profile

    def index_queryset(self, using=None):
        """Used when the entire index for the profile model is updated"""
        return self.get_model().objects.all()

    def prepare_tags(self, obj):
        return [tag.name for tag in obj.tags.all()]

    def prepare_username(self, obj):
        return obj.user.username

    def prepare_last_name(self, obj):
        print obj.user.last_name, " : <== LAST NAME\n"
        return obj.user.last_name# 

    def prepare_first_name(self, obj):
        print obj.user.first_name, " : <== FIRST NAME\n"
        return obj.user.first_name
```

I want the search result object to contain the first name and last name of user which is there in Django's default User model. How will I obtain such a result?

Comment: Do you mean by using it in `model_attr`?

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.io/en/v2.4.1/searchindex_api.html#advanced-data-preparation) you can find that `model_attr` can also look through relations:

> The `model_attr` keyword argument also can look through relations in models. So you can do something like `model_attr='author__first_name'` to pull just the first name of the author, similar to some lookups used by Django’s ORM.

So you can use:

```
username = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user__username')
first_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user__first_name')
last_name = indexes.CharField(model_attr='user__last_name')
```

Once you have done this, you don't need the prepare functions e.g. `prepare_first_name`, `prepare_last_name` etc.

Comment: {{ object.user.first_name }}
{{ object.user.last_name }}

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: what should i add in my text file to populate those field?I am new to elastic search so please forgive stupidity,also thanks for answering.

Comment: Which text file are you talking about? It is not mentioned in your question. I have answered the question based on how you have used prepare functions with `obj.user` assuming that `user` is a field on `Profile` model and a profile is linked to a user.